# XmlReader.ReadSubTree and reading Xml out of order

Tags: c#, filestream, saxparser, xmlreader

I have a large Xml file that I need to read efficiently. I cannot pull the whole thing into memory at once. However, I also need to do a limited amount of out-of-order processing on it, so reading it only once sequentially does not work. I hoped I could create a new `XmlReader` with `XmlReader.ReadSubTree()`, skip to the next sibling element with the original reader, continue parsing, and later go back and read the subtree using the new reader.

However, this doesn't appear to work. Looks like the new `XmlReaders` you create all use the same underlying stream, so advancing one advances them all.

However, if the stream underlying the reader supports seeking (as a filestream does), this should be possible.

I'm happy to parse the Xml sequentially twice (I don't see any way round this), but I don't want to do it `n` times, and ideally the code should be neat and maintainable.

Conceptually:

- Parse1: Parse the full Xml. Don't emit anything, but determine the start and end offsets of the `n` (non-intersecting) subtrees I want.
- Parse2: Read each subtree, however the order they are read in is not document order.

  - ParseSub(1): Seek to, then Read Subtree number `x_1`
  - ...
  - ParseSub(n): Seek to, then Read Subtree number `x_n`

If I can seek (to a known file offset), then Parse2 as a whole involves no more Xml reading than Parse1 - hence I'm reading the whole file twice. If I can't seek, then I guess I'm reading the whole file of the order of `n/2` times.

Comment: If the file is too big to fit into memory, perhaps XML is the wrong format for you... -- if you're forced to use XML, perhaps you can use a SAX parser to read the file into a database, and query it from there?

Comment: Fair comment, but we're stuck with Xml. After further investigation, I concluded that's it might be possible using reflection, but would be extremely fragile and not worth the effort.

Comment: Exactly, how big IS the XML file?

Comment: Also, Reflection for what?  SAX parsing?  if you Google for ".NET SAX Parser" (no quotes), the first two results look promising.  SAX parsing shouldn't require reflection.

Comment: I mean I can probably use reflection to dig into the XmlReader and underlying StreamReader to move the file offset around. As I said, not a fantastic idea.